# SonarQube C# CodeCoverage shows only line coverage

Tags: c#, sonarqube, code-coverage

SonarQube only shows 'Line coverage' in code coverage widget. To be precise, it shows 'Code coverage : 73.3%, Line coverage: 73.3%'. No class coverage, neither blocks.
But looking at my xml file with coverage data that I'm getting with VS CodeCoverage tool, it is there:

```
<module name="my.dll" path="my.dll" id="651BE0F83674FD4490D9E626C9DE4DE801000000" block_coverage="89.88" line_coverage="88.60" blocks_covered="231" blocks_not_covered="26" lines_covered="202" lines_partially_covered="3" lines_not_covered="23">
...
<module name="my2.dll" path="my2.dll" id="FE4C13CB7F7E104F982F937F4FDF113F01000000" block_coverage="70.17" line_coverage="74.35" blocks_covered="814" blocks_not_covered="346" lines_covered="687" lines_partially_covered="9" lines_not_covered="228">
```

You can see the lines/blocks coverage numbers.

I've running sonarqube 5.1.2, msbuild.runner for it.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you want to see, Indeed there is only line and branch coverage, from here you can drill down to files/class

To get branch coverage you need to use opencover

Comment: End even of case of OpenCover, this would require first this ticket to be fixed : https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARNTEST-4

Comment: Ye. Now I'm using OpenCover but still no branch coverage in sonar. Only lines 8(